# Getting member id of a specific member in telegram group

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot that can do several tasks in my telegram group.

I want to add a new task that can count the number of messages a specific user sends in a group.

Every time it will be updated, Let say a user name `drhunter`, if he sends a message then it will save in a text file as,
`drhunter 1` for the next message will be updated to `drhunter 2` and so on.

I can do it using  telegram username but If a user hasn't set username then occurs a problem. It shows `None`
I get username using `message.from_user.username`

I use username & count the number of messages each time then save it in a file. Like this

**count.txt**

> drhunter 5
>
> drhunter2 45

---

Is there any way to do this? or **more specifically is there any way to identify a telegram user without their username (inside a telegram group)?**

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`id`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user) instead, which is a unique identifier for the user independent of whether the user has a username.